# Add slick slider on home page Magento 2 via pagebuilder

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.2-p1, magento2.4.3.p1, magento242

I did check a lot of articles for a slick but none of them worked. Even I didn't see the js in view source code.

I want to add a slider on the homepage having multiple blocks. Can anyone help me out on this?

Rashi

Comment: You want to display product slider?

Comment: Yes, actually I purchased the extension to create blogs. I want to show that blog via slick slider using widget. Widget because, via widget only I can use that blogs

Comment: You need to add slick js and call into that div. as it's widget so, in widget you can't call slick using pagebuilder.

Comment: I did the same. Can't we add widget via pagebuilder in HTML CODE section & from there only can't we call our slick slider js?

Comment: You can call widget using page builder but can't apply slick in that widget. If you use slider or banner of page builder then it will be call pagebuilder's slick js.

Comment: then basically i have to call js in div file only if i want to use slick slider?

Comment: I added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a module, see [here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-add-slick-slider-in-magento-2/).
Then add the module to a block and integrate the block with the pagebuilder to the page.

Comment: thanks but didn't solved my requirement

Comment: I proposed basically the same solution as Rohan above – as far as I see it should help, isn't it?

Comment: yes sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mention in comment,

You can't add slick slider in widget using page builder. To implement slick slider in your widget. To add slick slider in your widget. You need to add this below code in your requirejs-config.js file.

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        slick: 'Vendor_Module/js/slick'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Then, add this below code in your common js file.

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'slick'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("your div id or class").slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });
    });
});
```

Reference : [Click Here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-add-slick-slider-in-magento-2/)

Comment: then how this will be applied to home page where i added the widget for blog?

Comment: FYI, this is the widget that contain all blogs i created -{{widget type="Magefan\Blog\Block\Widget\Recent" title="" no_repeat_posts_enable="0" number_of_posts="10" category_id="0" tag_id="0" author_id="0"}}. I want to move all  these 10 post in slick slider on home page. Hope my query is clear

Comment: It's quite simple that create custom js file then call that js file for home page. common js code add in your custom js file.

Comment: For ex : your div class is => widget widget-blog widget-blog-posts ... then you need to replace that your div id or class in slick js code

Comment: Mark as accept and upvote if it's useful for you.

Comment: Allow me sometime to check and confirm. Thanks for the spontaneous support